# Here Maps route : get crossed cities

Tags: maps, here-api

## Hello guys!

I'm actually using [Here](https://developer.here.com/documentation) to provide Maps. I'm actually using the [routing calculate](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) to calculate de distance between, duration and cities crossed two points. The problem is that the results don't contain any pieces of information about the crossed places.

### My Question:

How can I get the crossed Cities / Districts / Countries?

#### Here is an example:

I made this request here:
 `https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&mode=balanced;car;traffic:disabled&waypoint0=geo!48.13642,11.57755&waypoint1=geo!49.45435,11.0735&departure=2018-11-21T10:59:30.640Z&alternatives=5&routeAttributes=routeId&language=fr`

And the result was showing something with 26 legs in the route.

### Ideas:

- One idea was to go through all the Legs and find out which cities they belong to using another API, as those Legs contains Maneuver, which contains Position which is coordinate, but for me, it's too many resources used.
- Another Idea was to find out a way of adding metadata about it directly from the request but I didn't find anything about it in the documentation.

So I don't know yet what to do. Any help would be great!

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to request this from the Routing service. But there are different possibilities to request further deatails around the route itself:

*routeAttributes* - Defines which attributes are included in the response as part of the data representation of the route.

*legAttributes* - Defines which attributes are included in the response as part of the data representation of the route legs.

*maneuverAttributes* - Defines which attributes are included in the response as part of the data representation of the route
maneuvers.

*linkAttributes* - Defines which attributes are included in the response as part of the data representation of the route links.

See also here https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html

Maybe you can find here the right combination for your use case.

In anyway the Router offers the a summary by country:

> &routeattributes=sc

For example (I extended a bit your example to cross a country border):

```
 "summary": {
    "distance": 365910,
    "trafficTime": 15369,
    "baseTime": 14261,
    "flags": ["dirtRoad", "tollroad", "noThroughRoad", "tunnel", "motorway", "builtUpArea", "park"],
    "text": "Distance du trajet: 366 km, durée: 3h58.",
    "travelTime": 14261,
    "_type": "RouteSummaryType"
  },
  "summaryByCountry": [{
    "distance": 107955,
    "trafficTime": 5821,
    "baseTime": 5347,
    "flags": ["dirtRoad", "tollroad", "noThroughRoad", "tunnel", "motorway", "builtUpArea"],
    "text": "Distance du trajet: 108 km, durée: 1h29.",
    "travelTime": 5347,
    "country": "AUT",
    "tollRoadDistance": 94321,
    "_type": "RouteSummaryByCountryType"
  }, {
    "distance": 257955,
    "trafficTime": 9548,
    "baseTime": 8914,
    "flags": ["motorway", "builtUpArea", "park"],
    "text": "Distance du trajet: 258 km, durée: 2h29.",
    "travelTime": 8914,
    "country": "DEU",
    "_type": "RouteSummaryByCountryType"
  }]
```

Comment: Thank you! It was accurate as an answer.

Comment: How you fix your problem?